# Why my multithreaded quick sort didn't show speed advantage

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, sorting

So here is my code:

```
/**
 * Created by TianTuoYou on 4/7/16.
 */
public class MTQuickSort implements SortingAlgorithm {

    private int threadAmount = 1;

    @Override
    public void sort(int[] list) {
        QuickSortRunnable quickSortRunnable = new QuickSortRunnable(list, 0, list.length - 1);
        quickSortRunnable.run();
    }

    private class QuickSortRunnable implements Runnable {

        private int[] list;
        private int low;
        private int high;

        public QuickSortRunnable(int[] list, int low, int high) {
            this.list = list;
            this.low = low;
            this.high = high;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            quickSort(list, low, high);
        }

        private void quickSort(int[] list, int low, int high) {
            if (low < high) {
                int pivotLocation = partition(list, low, high);

                if (threadAmount < 5) {
                    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new QuickSortRunnable(list, low, pivotLocation - 1));
                    thread1.start();

                    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new QuickSortRunnable(list, pivotLocation + 1, high));
                    thread2.start();

                    threadAmount+=2;

                    try {
                        thread1.join();
                        thread2.join();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    quickSort(list, low, pivotLocation - 1);
                    quickSort(list, pivotLocation + 1, high);
                }
            }
        }

        private int partition(int[] list, int low, int high) {
            int pivot = list[high];
            int leftWall = low;

            int temp;
            for (int i = low; i < high; i ++) {
                if (list[i] <= pivot) {
                    leftWall ++;
                    temp = list[leftWall - 1];
                    list[leftWall - 1] = list[i];
                    list[i] = temp;
                }
            }

            temp = list[leftWall];
            list[leftWall] = list[high];
            list[high] = temp;

            return leftWall;
        }
    }
}
```

After I run test on this algorithm, I found that no matter how large the input is, it didn't show any faster than single thread quick sort, in most case it's even slower. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: There is overhead to starting, coordinating and communication between threads.

Comment: It could also be that your `pivot` happens to produce a relatively unbalanced pair of subproblems.

Comment: Just in case, How many cores do you have in your test machine?

Comment: When you say "no matter how large the input is", what was the max size of your input?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto 4 core i7, 8 virtual core due to hyper-threading.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto About 1000000

Answer (score 0):

`partition` occurs in the main sorting thread before you create any additional threads.  Your implementation of `partition` is O(N), which is the bulk of the cost of sorting anyway, and eliminates any real gains you could get by parallelizing the rest of it.

After `partition`, you create up to log(N) additional threads to re-partition your data within each thread, turning an O(N * log N) sort into an O(N ^ log N) - note the change from **multiply-by** to **to-the-power-of**.  Note that you have a race condition that allows up to 9 threads to be created, although you are most likely to see 5 or 7 in use, with 9 being extremely rare.

Since every layer of threads effectively re-sorts the whole list, you could end up performing at least `O(N^5)` move/compare operations.  For just one hundred elements to be sorted, this could require 20 million times as many operations as an actual quick-sort.

Note that you aren't likely to beat the built-in Java runtime sort, no matter how many cores you have - most of the Java runtime is written in C/C++ to avoid as much of the Java memory model's overhead as possible.  This is especially true for an array of small blocks such as integers.  Whenever you are able, use the runtime sort.

If you just want to do this for educational purposes, then you will want to focus on parallelizing the `partition` operation, and reduce the number of swaps that occur in it since that's where most of your cost is anyway.

Comment: Only the first instance of partition is called before threads are created, which probably doesn't matter much since partition will be main memory bound until partitions are small enough to fit in each core's local cache. To avoid the race condition, separate thread counts could be used for thread1 and thread2. I suspect the overall process is main memory bound, where each core's local caches doesn't help much.